# Gradle is not updating versionCode and VersionName to manifest.xml file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Based on the google documentation values which we use in gradle file like versionCode and versionName should be updated in manifest file. So in our case, We are trying to append a date and time to the versionCode in build.gradle file. But it seems like gradle is not updating the version code to manifest file. Is this the normal behavior?

**Gradle file**:

```
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format('yyMMddHHmm')
def code = formattedDate.toInteger()
android {    
  defaultConfig {
  versionCode code
  }
}
```

**Manifest file**:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="101" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.xxxx" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Are we missing any thing?

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: The greatest possible value for android:versionCode is MAXINT (2147483647). However, if you upload an app with this value, your app can't ever be updated.

**versionCode** — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.

**versionName** — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users.

You can solve whether you cut of the length of version code

```
def getDateTime() {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHH");
    return df.format(new Date()).toInteger();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding versionCode in productFlavours. Not sure why Gradle build is not picking the versionCode from defaultConfig block.

```
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format('yyMMddHH')
def code = formattedDate.toInteger()
productFlavors {
    Release {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode code
    }
```